# R2D3 - using remove() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using R2D3, the ie8 compatibility libraries for D3, and i've noticed that when i use the .remove() method it doesn't do anything. I can see that the svg is being removed on the modern browsers but not ie 8 even though i'm using R2D3.

Anyone knows if R2D3 handles the remove() method any differently? or if i have to call the event in another way?

```
d3.select("#animation").select("svg").remove();
```

Comment: You can't actually remove the SVG (Raphael Paper) through D3. It's a limitation of the current implementation. I'm pushing a new version through soon that will address this.